# Error using a module Component which is inside own library

Tags: angular, npm, module

I am not able to use a simple component which is in a simple module which is in a library

**Module (projects/atoms-library/src/lib/components/atoms/badges/badge/badge.module.ts)**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [BadgeComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  exports: [BadgeComponent],
})
export class BadgeModule { }
```

**public-api.ts**

```js
export * from './lib/components/atoms/badges/badge/badge.module';
```

I have this library published in npm and I can install it correctly in my project.

**app.module.ts**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    ...
    BadgeModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ..
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

But when a do a **ng serve** this is the error:

> *ERROR in Symbol BadgeComponent declared in /Users/growpro/Documents/projects/mymenu/node_modules/@gabiango/atoms-library/lib/components/atoms/badges/badge/badge.component.d.ts
> is not exported from
> @gabiango/atoms-library/lib/components/atoms/badges/badge/badge.module
> (import into
> /Users/growpro/Documents/projects/mymenu/src/app/app.component.ts)*

I don't understand why because the BadgeComponent is exported correctly in BadgeModule...

My angular dev environment is:

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.12
Node: 12.16.3
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 9.1.12
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... localize, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.12
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.12
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.12
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.12
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.12
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.12
@angular/cdk                      9.2.4
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.12
@schematics/angular               9.1.12
@schematics/update                0.901.12
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

Comment: hello. I know this is an old question but did you manage to solve this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your public-api.ts you need to export the component

export * from './lib/components/atoms/badges/badge/badge.component.ts';

Comment: It works! I did the assumption of auto-exporting components which are declared and exported in a module. It was logic for me... I guess it is the same procedure with directives and pipes, isn't it?

Comment: Yes ;)  All things you want to export